# how to change offroute distance and timeout?

Tags: android, here-api

Is there any configuration to change offroute distance threshold and timeout
especially on turning.Here maps got a late reroute start.
We are using here maps android premium sdk, positioning marker sometimes jumping to wrong route and makes rerouting then jumping back to correct position
there might me very small treshold set thats why on small gps jitters marker jumping around.

Comment: this feature has many map sdks like mapbox
if you don't understand the point you don't have to downvote but just ask :)
there is nothing about it in premium sdk developer guide.

Comment: Please, **stop!** adding tags to your post title! There is a special area for the tags, **under** the question text.

Comment: without adding here to title i was getting "title standart" error
after adding heremaps site accepted the question

Comment: Tags are tags. The don't go in the title area. If you get a duplicate title, then modify the title description slightly (i.e.: by adding a `?` or something). You're right it's a site limitation. You can have users with the same name (which I personally find offending, since each individual SHOULD be uniquely identified), but you can't have two questions with the same title!

Answer (score 0):

That parameter is not exposed in the API and not available for public tweaking.

Comment: currently positioning is very sensitive to location noises/jitters.
jumping to wrong roads and reroutes. i guess there is no kalman or other location data filters applied like on other navigation engines (sygic,mapbox,telenav etc)